# Mocking Vue class component methods with inject loader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Let's say I have a very basic **vue-class-component** as shown below:

```
<template>
    <div>Nothing of interest here</div>
</template>

<script>
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import Component from 'vue-class-component';
    import http from './../modules/http';

    @Component
    export default class Example extends Vue {
        user = null;
        errors = null;

        /**
         * @returns {string}
         */
        getUserId() {
            return this.$route.params.userId;
        }

        fetchUser() {
            this.user = null;
            this.errors = null;

            http.get('/v1/auth/user/' + this.getUserId())
                .then(response => this.user = response.data)
                .catch(e => this.errors = e);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want to test the `fetchUser()` method so I just mock the `'./../modules/http'` dependency and make `http.get` return a `Promise`. The problem is that in my assertion I want to check if the URL is being built properly and in order to do so the user ID has to come from an hard-coded variable in the test.

I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
import ExampleInjector from '!!vue-loader?inject!./../../../src/components/Example.vue';

const mockedComponent = ExampleInjector({
    './../modules/http': {
        get: () => new Promise(/* some logic */)
    },
    methods: getUserId: () => 'my_mocked_user_id'
});
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I could not find anything this specific in the Vue docs so the question is, *how am I supposed to mock both external dependencies and a class component method?*

**NOTE:** I do not want to mock `this.$route.params.userId` as the `userId` could potentially come from somewhere else as well (plus this is just an example). I just want to mock the `getUserId` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I specifically asked about how I could **mock Vue class component methods with the inject loader** here's the complete solution for the question at hand:

```
import ExampleInjector from '!!vue-loader?inject!./../../../src/components/Example.vue';

const getComponentWithMockedUserId = (mockedUserId, mockedComponent = null, methods = {}) => {
    if (!mockedComponent) {
        mockedComponent = ExampleInjector();
    }

    return Vue.component('test', {
        extends: mockedComponent,
        methods: {
            getUserId: () => mockedUserId,
            ...methods
        }
    });
};
```

And then in my test case:

```
const component = getComponentWithMockedUserId('my_mocked_user_id');

const vm = new Vue(component);
```

I found this to be very helpful when you need to create a partial mock **AND** inject some dependencies too.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to extend the component and override the method:

```
const Foo = Vue.extend({
  template: `<div>{{iAm}}</div>`,
  created() {
    this.whoAmI();
  },
  methods: {
    whoAmI() {
      this.iAm = 'I am foo';
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      iAm: ''
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('bar', {
  extends: Foo,
  methods: {
    whoAmI() {
      this.iAm = 'I am bar';
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

In this example I'm using the `extends` property to tell `Vue` that `Bar` extends `Foo` and then I'm overriding the `whoAmI` method, you can see this is action here: https://jsfiddle.net/pxr34tuz/

I use something similar in one of my open source projects, which you can check out [here](https://github.com/craigh411/vue-star-rating/blob/master/spec/star.spec.js#L75). All I'm doing in that example is switching off the required property for the props to stop Vue throwing console errors at me.

Comment: Can you make your example complete by mocking also external modules like I'm doing in my question with the `inject-loader` please?

Comment: @FrancescoCasula Do you mean when importing single file components?

Comment: yes like in the second snippet of code in my question where I'm doing `const mockedComponent = ExampleInjector({...`. I think it works if you just pass `mockedComponent` on `extends` in the `Vue.component` call. In my case I also had to do `const component = Vue.component(/*...*/)` and then `const vm = new Vue(component);` or it wouldn't work, perhaps because there's no mounting in my test.